# Can a Wi-Fi device be a WAP and provide internet connectivity simultaneously?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, usb

I’m working on a project where we are using two Wi-Fi dongles, one to provide a WAP and the other for connectivity.

However, setting this up in Ubuntu is a royal pain.

Is it even possible for one Wi-Fi device to do both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most consumer grade 802.11 devices are not capable of *master mode*, which is needed for an access point.

Depending on the sophistication of the 802.11 device, it may or may not support concurrent master/client modes.  Some do.  An entry level device which supports master mode is the [Alpha](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001O9X9EU).  It is cheap and reliable.

You can look at HostAP, which is a reasonably easy to use application for configuring everything from simple to uber AP.

However, HostAP, as any other solution, will be limited by whether or not your hardware supports being in AP mode.

The HostAP [website](http://w1.fi/) has a list of supported devices.  Additionally, I think the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HostAP) page has useful information.

One thing to remember -- the device brand/model is completely irrelevant -- you **must** look at the 802.11 chipset to determine if that supports master mode.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Because access point mode requires a fixed channel, however, the client is also limited to this channel. Only with multiple radios—pretty much your current setup—can you bypass this limitation.

And then there’s also the fact that you can’t bridge Wi-Fi client interfaces to Ethernet interfaces or Wi-Fi host interfaces. So unless using `relayd` or something similar, you’re limited to a routing setup with different subnets.

Ubuntu was never designed to operate as a full-blown network router. I suggest you switch to a distribution with advanced network configuration capabilities. Without [NetworkManager](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager), of course. You might even have some success with just getting rid of any “intelligent” network switching/configuration system. It’s still basically Debian underneath, I guess.

Gentoo, although it introduces overhead by compiling everything from source, has an extremely flexible network configuration system. I find Gentoo very easy to manage in general, but it certainly isn’t everyone’s cup of tea.

Arch Linux also provides sort-of advanced net configuration via [`netctl`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/netctl). I’m not overly familiar with but used it successfully to make my notebook into a 3G-Wi-Fi router while moving.

Comment: I wanted to upvote. But the suggestion to switch to a distribution with advanced network configuration capabilities and without NetworkManager is entirely useless. You can use just any distribution including Ubuntu to expose Linux routing / network configuration capabilities. Also, as a Gentoo user, I wouldn't recommend it for this purpose unless the OP explicitly wishes to play with kernel networking configuration as there's nothing like a universal kernel configuration or image in Gentoo. I generally found only the first two paragraphs of any use.